# Unable to create Controller to a Class with a DropDown type of property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, dropdown

I've have a basic Class while using MVC C#:

```
public class Page
{
    //Bunch of files with Annotations

    [Display(Name = "Page Type")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
    public Guid? PageTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageTypeID")]
    public virtual PageType PageType { get; set; }
}
```

When I build the Scaffolding, the following code will produce an error:

```
There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Unable to retrieve metadata from 'MyNamespace.Page'.'
```

I've rebuilt, cleaned, restart VS, none of that helps.

Removing the following code

```
[ForeignKey("PageTypeID")]
```

Will allow the Scaffolding to be created but then my Drop Down is a Text Field.

I also have this setup, that seems to work, and doesn't make sense to me so I am looking to better understand.  Replacing DropDownItem with PageType will still produce the same error as above.

```
[Display(Name = "Drop Down Item")]
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "N/A")]
public Guid? DropDownItemID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("DropDownItemID")]
public virtual DropDownItem DropDownItem { get; set; }
```

PageType class is the following:

```
public class PageType : DropDownItem
{
    public new string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DropDownItem is the following:

```
public class DropDownItem : BaseObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

## Update #1

I am using EntityFramework 6.1.3 and is referenced to my Project

I believe that I was missing the Get/Set of PageType in the ApplicationDBContext

Before

```
public class ApplicationDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDBContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") { }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DropDownItem> DropDownItems { get; set; }

}
```

After (just added this line)

```
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PageType> PageTypes { get; set; }
```

**Correct me if I am wrong**, but I believe that this wasn't working for me because the above line of code (DbSet) wasn't there, it wasn't there because I forgot to add a Controller for it (ie: PageTypesController), from there, I would have been able to add PageType to the Page object.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? So then can you add the DbContext implementation then?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Updated the initial question, I believe it is resolved.

Comment: That correct. You need to add the DbSet to make the scaffold to work